# Как перебрать все inputs и записать в бд в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте. Подскажите: Есть интпуты такого типа

```
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="fabricator[]">
<input type="text" name="value[]">
```

Эта группа инпутов, будет задаваться в неопределенном количестве пользователем, то есть динамика. Так вот, вопрос, как перебрать эти массивы всех инпутов и записать в бд или как ещё сделать лучше? 
Пока сделал ток перебор по одному массиву, а можно ли сразу как-то все перебрать и в бд отправить?

```
foreach($request->name as $key => $val ) {
    $param = Flavors::create(['name' => $val); 
}
```

Comment: вы спрашиваете, что можно сделать лучше, но не говорите о том, что вам нужно сделать. В вашем случае, насколько я понимаю, нужен просто двойной вложенный цикл. Хотя, задача неясна, и, возможно, вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: Группа инпутов будет в неопределенном количестве, пользователь будет сам выбирать. Дальше допустим при клике нужно собрать все данные с инпутов и отправить в бд. вот так: первая группа из инпутов name[0], fabricator[0], value[0] - это одна запись в таблице, далльше если есть name[1], fabricator[1], value[1] то добавить как вторую запись в таблице и так далее... И можно ли это как то одним запросом отправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала собираете данные в один массив, а затем с помощью insert Eloquent вставляете в БД.

```
$data = [];
$fabricator = $request->fabricator;
$valueInput = $request->value;

foreach($request->name as $key => $val ) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $fabricator) && array_key_exists($key, $valueInput)){
        $data[$key] = [
            'name' => $val,
            'fabricator' => $request->fabricator[$key],
            'value' => $request->value[$key]
        ];
    }
}
if($data){
    $param = Flavors::insert($data);
}
```